# Only a ui.Widget can be added to a panel

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am new to the GEE platform.

When creating UI, the compiler for some reason started swearing at this line, but why it is swearing I don't understand, according to the syntax everything seems to be correct.

And the compiler explains the error in the following way:

> Line 41: Only a ui.Widget can be added to a panel.

```
var app = {};

/** Создает панели пользовательского интерфейса. */
app.createPanels = function() {
  /* Вводный раздел */
  app.intro = {
    panel: ui.Panel([
      ui.Label({
        value: 'Landsat 8 Explorer',
        style: {fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '24px', margin: '10px 5px'}
      }),
      ui.Label('Это приложение позволяет фильтровать и ' +
               'экспортировать изображения из коллекции Landsat 8.')
    ])
  };
  
  /* Фильтр сбора контролирует. */
  app.filters = {
    mapCenter: ui.Checkbox({label: 'Filter to map center', value: true}),
    startDate: ui.Textbox('YYYY-MM-DD', '2020-01-01'),
    endDate: ui.Textbox('YYYY-MM-DD', '2020-12-01'),
    applyButton: ui.Button('Apply filters', app.applyFilters),
    loadingLabel: ui.Label({
      value: 'Загрузка...',
      style: {stretch: 'vertical', color: 'gray', shown: false}
    })
  };
  
  /* Панель для виджетов управления фильтрами. */
  app.filters.panel = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [
      ui.Label('1) Выберите фильтры', {fontWeight: 'bold'}),
      ui.Label('от какой даты', app.HELPER_TEXT_STYLE), app.filters.startDate,
      ui.Label('до какой даты', app.HELPER_TEXT_STYLE), app.filters.endDate,
      app.filters.mapCenter,
      ui.Panel([
        app.filters.appluButton,
        app.filters.loadingLabel
      ], ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'))        
    ],
    style: app.SECTION_STYLE
  });
  
  /* Раздел выбора изображений */
  app.picker = {
    // Создайте select с функцией, реагирующей на событие "change".
    select: ui.Select({
      placeholder: 'Select an image ID',
      onChange: app.refreshMapLayer
    }),
    // Создайте кнопку, которая центрирует карту на заданном объекте.
    centerButton: ui.Button('Center on map', function() {
      Map.centerObject(Map.layers().get(0).get('eeObject'));
    })
  };
  
  /* Панель для раздела picker с соответствующими виджетами. */
  app.picker.panel = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [
      ui.Label('2) Выберите изображение', {fontWeight: 'bold'}),
      ui.Panel([
        app.picker.select,
        app.picker.centerButton
      ], ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'))
    ],
    style: app.SECTION_STYLE
  });
  
  /* Раздел визуализации */
  app.vis = {
    label: ui.Label(),
    // Создайте select с функцией, реагирующей на событие "change".
    select: ui.Select({
      items: Object.keys(app.VIS_OPTIONS),
      OnChange: function() {
        // Обновление значения метки описанием селекта.
        var option = app.VIS_OPTIONS[app.vis.select.getValue()];
        app.vis.label.setValue(option.description);
        // Refresh the map layer.
        app.refleshMapLayer();
      }
    })
  };
  
  /* Панель для раздела визуализации с соответствующими виджетами. */
  app.vis.panel = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [
    ui.Label('3) Выберите визуализацию', {fontWeight: 'bold'}),
    app.vis.select,
    app.vis.label
    ],
    style: app.SECTION_STYLE
  });
  
  // По умолчанию для выбора используется первое значение.
  app.vis.select.setValue(app.vis.select.items().get(0));
  
  /* Раздел экспорта. */
  app.export = {
    button: ui.Button({
      label: 'Экспорт текущего изображения на диск',
      // Реагирует на событие нажатия кнопки.
      OnClick: function() {
        // Выберите полный идентификатор изображения.
        var imageIdTrailer = app.picker.select.getValue();
        var imageId = app.COLLECTION_ID + '/' + imageIdTrailer;
        // Получите варианты визуализации.
        var visOption = app.VIS_OPTIONS[app.vis.select.getValue()];
        // Экспортируйте изображение в Drive.
        Export.image.toDrive({
          image: ee.Image(imageId).select(visOption.visParams.bands),
          description: 'L8_Export-' + imageIdTrailer,
        });
      }
    })
  };
  
  /* Панель для раздела экспорта с соответствующими виджетами. */
  app.export.panel = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [
      ui.Label('4) Выберите экспорт', {fontWeight: 'bold'}),
      app.export.button
    ],
    style: app.SECTION_STYLE
  });
};

/** Создает вспомогательные функции приложения. */
app.createHelpers = function() {
/**
 * Включает или выключает режим загрузки
 * @param {boolean} enabled Включен ли режим загрузки.
 */
app.setLoadingMode = function(enabled) { 
  // Установите видимость загрузочной метки во включенном режиме.
  app.filters.loadingLabel.style().set('shown', enabled);
  // Установите каждый из виджетов в заданный включенный режим.
  var loadDependentWidgets = [
    app.vis.select,
    app.filters.startDate,
    app.filters.endDate,
    app.filters.applyButton,
    app.filters.mapCenter,
    app.picker.select,
    app.picker.centerButton,
    app.export.button
  ];
  loadDependentWidgets.forEach(function(widget) {
     widget.setDisabled(enabled);
  });
};

/* Применяет фильтры выбора, выбранные в настоящее время в UI. */
app.applyFilters = function() {
  app.setLoadingMode(true);
  var filtered = ee.ImageCollection(app.COLLECTION_ID);
  
  // Фильтр границ карты, если флажок отмечен.
  if (app.filters.mapCenter.getValue()) {
    filtered = filtered.filterBounds(Map.getCenter());
  }
  
  // Установите переменные фильтра.
  var start = app.fulters.startDate.getValue();
  if (start) start = ee.Date(start);
  var end = app.fulters.endDate.getValue();
  if (end) end = ee.Date(end);
  if (start) filtered = filtered.filterDate(start, end);
  
  // Получить список вычисленных идентификаторов.
  var computedIds = filtered
      .limit(app.IMAGE_COUNT_LIMIT)
      .reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.tolist(), ['system:index'])
      .get('list');
      
  computedIds.evaluate(function(ids) {
    // Обновление подборщика изображений с заданным списком идентификаторов.
    app.setLoadingMode(false);
    app.picker.select.items().reset(ids);
    // По умолчанию выборщик изображений выбирает первый идентификатор.
    app.picker.select.setValue(app.picker.select.items().get(0));
  });
};

/** Обновляет текущий слой карты на основе состояний виджетов UI. */
app.refreshMapLayer = function() {
  Map.clear();
  var iamgeId = app.picker.select.getValue();
  if (imageId) {
    // Если идентификатор изображения найден, создайте изображение.
    var image = ee.Image(app>COLLECTION_ID + '/' + imageId);
    // Добавление изображения на карту с соответствующими опциями визуализации.
    var visOption = app.VIS_OPTIONS[app.vis.select.getValue()];
    Map.addLayer(image, visOption.visParam, imageId);
  }
};
};

/** Создает компоненты приложения. */
app.createConstants = function() {
app.COLLECTION_ID = 'LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA';
app.SECTION_STYLE = {margin: '20px 0 0 0'};
app.HELPER_TEXT_STYLE = {
    margin: '8px 0 -3px 8px',
    fontSize: '12px',
    color: 'gray'
};
app.IMAGE_COUNT_LIMIT = 10;
app.VIS_OPTIONS = {
  'False color (B7/B6/B4)': {
    description: 'Растительность - оттенки красного, городские районы - ' +
                 'голубого, а почвы - коричневого.',
    visParams: {gamma: 1.3, min: 0, max: 0.3, bands: ['B7', 'B6', 'B4']}
  },
  'Natural color (B4/B3/B2)': {
    description: 'Наземные объекты отображаются в цветах, аналогичных их ' +
                 'внешнему виду для зрительной системы человека.',
    visParams: {gamma: 1.3, min: 0, max: 0.3, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']}
  },
  'Atmospheric (B7/B6/B5)': {
    description: 'Береговые линии и берега четко определены. ' +
                 'Растительность кажется синей.',
    visParams: {gamma: 1.3, min: 0, max: 0.3, bands: ['B7', 'B6', 'B5']}
  }
};
};

/** Создает интерфейс приложения. */
app.boot = function() {
app.createConstants();
app.createHelpers();
app.createPanels();
var main = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [
    app.intro.panel,
    app.filters.panel,
    app.picker.panel,
    app.vis.panel,
    app.export.panel
  ],
  style: {width: '320px', padding: '8px'}
});
Map.setCenter(-97, 26, 9);
ui.root.insert(0, main);
app.applyFilters();
};

app.boot();
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many typos in your script. Therefore, it throws a lot of errors. The following code is its corrected version:

```
var app = {};

/** Создает панели пользовательского интерфейса. */
app.createPanels = function () {
  /* Вводный раздел */
  app.intro = {
    panel: ui.Panel([
      ui.Label({
        value: 'Landsat 8 Explorer',
        style: { fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '24px', margin: '10px 5px' }
      }),
      ui.Label('Это приложение позволяет фильтровать и ' +
        'экспортировать изображения из коллекции Landsat 8.')
    ])
  };

  /* Фильтр сбора контролирует. */
  app.filters = {
    mapCenter: ui.Checkbox({ label: 'Filter to map center', value: true }),
    startDate: ui.Textbox('YYYY-MM-DD', '2020-01-01'),
    endDate: ui.Textbox('YYYY-MM-DD', '2020-12-01'),
    applyButton: ui.Button('Apply filters', app.applyFilters),
    loadingLabel: ui.Label({
      value: 'Загрузка...',
      style: { stretch: 'vertical', color: 'gray', shown: false }
    })
  };

  /* Панель для виджетов управления фильтрами. */
  app.filters.panel = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [
      ui.Label('1) Выберите фильтры', { fontWeight: 'bold' }),
      ui.Label('от какой даты', app.HELPER_TEXT_STYLE),
      app.filters.startDate,
      ui.Label('до какой даты', app.HELPER_TEXT_STYLE),
      app.filters.endDate,
      app.filters.mapCenter,
      ui.Panel([app.filters.applyButton,
      app.filters.loadingLabel],
        ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'))
    ],
    style: app.SECTION_STYLE
  });

  /* Раздел выбора изображений */
  app.picker = {
    // Создайте select с функцией, реагирующей на событие "change".
    select: ui.Select({
      placeholder: 'Select an image ID',
      onChange: app.refreshMapLayer
    }),
    // Создайте кнопку, которая центрирует карту на заданном объекте.
    centerButton: ui.Button('Center on map', function () {
      Map.centerObject(Map.layers().get(0).get('eeObject'));
    })
  };

  /* Панель для раздела picker с соответствующими виджетами. */
  app.picker.panel = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [
      ui.Label('2 Выберите изображение', { fontWeight: 'bold' }),
      ui.Panel([
        app.picker.select,
        app.picker.centerButton
      ], ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'))],
    style: app.SECTION_STYLE
  });

  /* Раздел визуализации */
  app.vis = {
    label: ui.Label(),
    // Создайте select с функцией, реагирующей на событие "change".
    select: ui.Select({
      items: Object.keys(app.VIS_OPTIONS),
      onChange: function () {
        // Обновление значения метки описанием селекта.
        var option = app.VIS_OPTIONS[app.vis.select.getValue()];
        app.vis.label.setValue(option.description);
        // Refresh the map layer.
        app.refreshMapLayer();
      }
    })
  };

  /* Панель для раздела визуализации с соответствующими виджетами. */
  app.vis.panel = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [
      ui.Label('3 Выберите визуализацию', { fontWeight: 'bold' }),
      app.vis.select,
      app.vis.label
    ],
    style: app.SECTION_STYLE
  });

  // По умолчанию для выбора используется первое значение.
  app.vis.select.setValue(app.vis.select.items().get(0));

  /* Раздел экспорта. */
  app.export = {
    button: ui.Button({
      label: 'Экспорт текущего изображения на диск',
      // Реагирует на событие нажатия кнопки.
      onClick: function () {
        // Выберите полный идентификатор изображения.
        var imageIdTrailer = app.picker.select.getValue();
        var imageId = app.COLLECTION_ID + '/' + imageIdTrailer;
        // Получите варианты визуализации.
        var visOption = app.VIS_OPTIONS[app.vis.select.getValue()];
        // Экспортируйте изображение в Drive.
        Export.image.toDrive({
          image: ee.Image(imageId).select(visOption.visParams.bands),
          description: 'L8_Export-' + imageIdTrailer,
        });
      }
    })
  };

  /* Панель для раздела экспорта с соответствующими виджетами. */
  app.export.panel = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [
      ui.Label('4 Выберите экспорт', { fontWeight: 'bold' }),
      app.export.button
    ],
    style: app.SECTION_STYLE
  });
};

/** Создает вспомогательные функции приложения. */
app.createHelpers = function () {
  /**
   * Включает или выключает режим загрузки
   * @param {boolean} enabled Включен ли режим загрузки.
   */
  app.setLoadingMode = function (enabled) {
    // Установите видимость загрузочной метки во включенном режиме.
    app.filters.loadingLabel.style().set('shown', enabled);
    // Установите каждый из виджетов в заданный включенный режим.
    var loadDependentWidgets = [
      app.vis.select,
      app.filters.startDate,
      app.filters.endDate,
      app.filters.applyButton,
      app.filters.mapCenter,
      app.picker.select,
      app.picker.centerButton,
      app.export.button
    ];
    loadDependentWidgets.forEach(function (widget) {
      widget.setDisabled(enabled);
    });
  };

  /* Применяет фильтры выбора, выбранные в настоящее время в UI. */
  app.applyFilters = function () {
    app.setLoadingMode(true);
    var filtered = ee.ImageCollection(app.COLLECTION_ID);

    // Фильтр границ карты, если флажок отмечен.
    if (app.filters.mapCenter.getValue()) {
      filtered = filtered.filterBounds(Map.getCenter());
    }

    // Установите переменные фильтра.
    var start = app.filters.startDate.getValue();
    if (start) start = ee.Date(start);
    var end = app.filters.endDate.getValue();
    if (end) end = ee.Date(end);
    if (start) filtered = filtered.filterDate(start, end);

    // Получить список вычисленных идентификаторов.
    var computedIds = filtered
      .limit(app.IMAGE_COUNT_LIMIT)
      .reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), ['system:index'])
      .get('list');

    computedIds.evaluate(function (ids) {
      // Обновление подборщика изображений с заданным списком идентификаторов.
      app.setLoadingMode(false);
      app.picker.select.items().reset(ids);
      // По умолчанию выборщик изображений выбирает первый идентификатор.
      app.picker.select.setValue(app.picker.select.items().get(0));
    });
  };

  /** Обновляет текущий слой карты на основе состояний виджетов UI. */
  app.refreshMapLayer = function () {
    Map.clear();
    var imageId = app.picker.select.getValue();
    if (imageId) {
      // Если идентификатор изображения найден, создайте изображение.
      var image = ee.Image(app.COLLECTION_ID + '/' + imageId);
      // Добавление изображения на карту с соответствующими опциями визуализации.
      var visOption = app.VIS_OPTIONS[app.vis.select.getValue()];
      Map.addLayer(image, visOption.visParam, imageId);
    }
  };
};

/** Создает компоненты приложения. */
app.createConstants = function () {
  app.COLLECTION_ID = 'LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT_TOA';
  app.SECTION_STYLE = { margin: '20px 0 0 0' };
  app.HELPER_TEXT_STYLE = {
    margin: '8px 0 -3px 8px',
    fontSize: '12px',
    color: 'gray'
  };
  app.IMAGE_COUNT_LIMIT = 10;
  app.VIS_OPTIONS = {
    'False color (B7/B6/B4)': {
      description: 'Растительность - оттенки красного, городские районы - ' +
        'голубого, а почвы - коричневого.',
      visParams: { gamma: 1.3, min: 0, max: 0.3, bands: ['B7', 'B6', 'B4'] }
    },
    'Natural color (B4/B3/B2)': {
      description: 'Наземные объекты отображаются в цветах, аналогичных их ' +
        'внешнему виду для зрительной системы человека.',
      visParams: { gamma: 1.3, min: 0, max: 0.3, bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'] }
    },
    'Atmospheric (B7/B6/B5)': {
      description: 'Береговые линии и берега четко определены. ' +
        'Растительность кажется синей.',
      visParams: { gamma: 1.3, min: 0, max: 0.3, bands: ['B7', 'B6', 'B5'] }
    }
  };
};

/** Создает интерфейс приложения. */
app.boot = function () {
  app.createConstants();
  app.createHelpers();
  app.createPanels();
  var main = ui.Panel({
    widgets: [
      app.intro.panel,
      app.filters.panel,
      app.picker.panel,
      app.vis.panel,
      app.export.panel
    ],
    style: { width: '320px', padding: '8px' }
  });
  Map.setCenter(-97, 26, 9);
  ui.root.insert(0, main);
  app.applyFilters();
};

app.boot();
```

Result:

[image]